# Unable to find null bytes in Python code in Pycharm?

Tags: python, null, pycharm

During copy/pasting code I often get `null` bytes in Python code. Python itself reports general error against module and doesn't specify location of null byte. IDE of my choice like PyCharm, doesn't have check for this and doesn't see null bytes in code.

So, what is the general way to find `null` bytes in Python code?

---

```
λ cat main.py
import helloworld
λ cat helloworld.py
print('Hello world! ')
λ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import helloworld
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

λ python helloworld.py
  File "helloworld.py", line 1
    print('Hello world!
                      ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

λ cat -A helloworld.py
print('Hello world!^@')
```

Comment: There is no `null` byte in Python. Primitive datatype such as byte can only have values in all languages I know.  IMHO there's even no `byte` datatype in Python at all. So either you're talking about a byte sequence, which could be `None` or something else. Maybe it would be best to show your code.

Comment: It is "official" error message, I can generate it for you if you don't beleive.

Comment: Yes, please, some code would be nice

Comment: See it. NULL byte is between exclamation mark and closing quote.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely caused by copy/paste, since it's hard to type such a character on the keyboard.

> So, what is the general way to find null bytes in Python code?

IMHO there's no need to check for NUL chcracters in your source code every time. I'm working with source code for >10 years now, and I've never had such a copy/paste issue, even I use copy/paste for many prototypes and MCVEs.

So, the trigger to check the source code is exactly an error message such as the one from Python.

Which tool to use? A hex editor, since it will display the NUL character. For Windows, my choice is the freeware [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/).

[image: Finding NUL byte in HxD]

On Linux, the command `grep -Pa '\x00' helloworld.py` should be fine.